# Why doesn't my Entity Framework app work on production server?

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, iis-6, asp.net-3.5

I get following error when deploying on test server with II6 and Framework 3.5 SP1 installed.

> The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly
>   reference

My development machine is a 64bit pc with Visual Studio 2008.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though the .net assembly is unable to find the correct version that you are after.  Make sure you put the assembly definition in the GAC.  You may need to look at the GAC and remove the old version and then rebuild.

In other words, go to your production server and look for any assemblies (.dll files) that are currently loaded on that server.  The version on your production server may not match the reference of your local machine's project.

Once you find it remove it and replace it with what your application is using.

Comment: for examples System.Data.Linq on dev has version 3.5.30729.4926 and on production has 3.5.30729.1. Is this something to look out for...

Could you explain a little more which steps to take. (btw, do i need to restart af installing Framework 3.5 SP1)

Comment: @Sander Versluys - You will need to check the versions of your development environment versus your production environment.  Use the GAC or manually remove the assemblies (the ones that do not match) from your prod server and replace them with assemblies that your project is using (the latest version).  Then rebuild.

Comment: I've used the 3.5 SP1 setup en repaired the installation. Appearently it refreshed the GAC (because some version numbers changed) and now my app is able to run! Thanks for the tips! ;-)